# OpenCSV returns a string even when there is no value in the CSV row

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, opencsv

I'm writing a program to check if the first two rows, excluding the header, contain any data or not. If they do not, the file is to be ignored, and if either of the first two rows contain data, then process the file. I am using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to retrieve the header, the first row and the second row into 3 different arrays and then checking them for my requirements. My problem is that even if the first two rows are empty, the `reader` returns something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@13f17c9e` as the output of the first and/or second row (depending on my test files).

Why does it return anything at all, other than a `null`, that is?

Comment: Would that be an empty string array?

Comment: I'm expecting it to be one. But instead has the value similar to the one in the question.

Comment: An empty string array is not the same as null - it's still a valid object and would give a result similar to what you describe if, for example, you applied .toString() to it. What is the result of .length()? I'm guessing 0...

Comment: This is really weird. In the file, there are 17 columns, but I have removed the values from the first two rows, for test purposes. The length is 17, but the values themselves, fill 17 blank rows in the console before my debug message appears. What is going on?

Comment: Also, the output of `sysout array.toString()` is the junk value given in the question..

Comment: I elaborated in the form of an answer below. If it doesn't help, could you alter your question to show a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my computer right now so excuse any mistakes~ The OpenCSV API Javadocs is rather brief but there doesn't seem to be much to it. Reading a line should parse the content into an array of strings. An empty line should result in an empty string array which gives something like `[Ljava.lang.String;@13f17c9e` if you try to print it out...

I would assume that the following example file:

```
1 |
2 |
3 | "The above lines are empty", 12345, "foo"
```

would produce the following if you did myCSVReader.readAll()

```
// List<String[]> result = myCSVReader.readAll();
0 : []
1 : []
2 : ["The above lines are empty","12345","foo"]
```

To perform what you describe in your question, test for length instead of some sort of null checking or string comparison.

```
List<String> lines = myCSVReader.readAll();

// lets print the output of the first three lines
for (int i=0, i<3, i++) {
  String[] lineTokens = lines.get(i);
  System.out.println("line:" + (i+1) + "\tlength:" + lineTokens.length);
  // print each of the tokens
  for (String token : lineTokens) {
    System.out.println("\ttoken: " + token);
  }
}

// only process the file if lines two or three aren't empty
if (lineTokens.get(1).length > 0 || lineTokens.get(2).length > 0) {
  System.out.println("Process this file!");
  processFile(lineTokens);
}
else {
  System.out.println("Skipping...!");
}

// EXPECTED OUTPUT:
// line:1  length:0
// line:2  length:0
// line:3  length:3
//         token: The above lines are empty
//         token: 12345
//         token: foo
// Process this file!
```

Comment: Of course, you should just read the first three lines using `readNext()` instead of the whole file with `readAll()` (especially if the files are really large).

Comment: I had just figured out that I needed to check the lengths of the tokens rather than if they are null. Although, the way I did it was just brute force rather than put any reasoning behind it.. :P